# Тревога со статусом "устарел"

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

В истории моих тревог появилась тревога со статусом "устарел".

Что означает этот статус? И кто устарел вопрос или тревога?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Устарела **тревога**. [Здесь описаны правила](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204347/318749):

> #### Тревоги "грубый или оскорбительный" на сообщениях
>
> Устаревают через 2 дня.
>
> #### Тревоги "грубый или оскорбительный" на комментариях
>
> Устаревают через 4 дня.
>
> #### Тревоги с рекомендацией закрыть вопрос
>
> Действуют [обычные правила устаревания голосов за закрытие](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120902):
>
> - Для тревог про перенос (миграцию): устаревают, когда вопрос становится слишком старым для переноса, это 60 дней.
> - Раз в день на вопросе устаревает самая старая тревога про закрытие, при условии что с последнего голоса (не тревоги, *прим. пер.*) за закрытие прошло:
>
>   - 4 дня, если у вопроса 100+ просмотров
>   - 14 дней, если у вопроса меньше 100 просмотров
>
> Заметьте: если на тревогу в процессе проверок голосов за закрытие вопрос получит три "оставить открытым", тревога будет *отклонена*, а не устареет.