# Непонятное состояние при попытке проголосовать за закрытие вопроса после отмены прошлого голоса

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия, голосование

1. Голосовать за закрытие.
2. Отменить голос, чтоб выбрать другую причину.
3. Открыть окно для голосования. Не понятное состояние. Что мне сделать, чтоб проголосовать?

> Вы голосовали за закрытие данного вопроса 1 минуту назад
>
> Вы отозвали свой голос 1 минуту назад

О чём должен текст про время говорить? Если указано время голосования, то значит, что через какое-то время я смогу снова проголосовать? Если нет, то зачем вообще указано время?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При отмене голоса за закрытие выводится предупреждение, что повторно голосовать уже будет нельзя. Вы соглашаетесь с этим, когда отзываете свой голос. То есть выбрать новую причину уже нельзя даже если вопрос потом переоткроют.

Время указывается просто чтобы знать когда произошло то или иное событие. Это как запись в журнале.

Посмотрел по истории своих голосов за закрытие, выяснил следующее:

- Если ваш голос способствовал закрытию вопроса или был отозван самостоятельно, то повторное голосование на этом вопросе вам уже выполнить нельзя даже в случае дальнейшего переоткрытия вопроса;
- Если за [определённое время](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5474/176217) не набралось достаточного кол-ва голосов для закрытия вопроса, то такие голоса сгорают и после этого можно голосовать повторно.

Comment: Голоса аннулируются же. Уверен, что через пару недель или месяцев проголосовать нельзя будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy добавил инфы в ответ.

Comment: Ага, прочитал )